# How to Parse Methods and Functions to Log the Code

Tags: php, parsing

Is there an easy way to parse the Functions and their code from a PHP file so you can log the contents of each function separately in a database?

I would like to log each separate function and the comments for the function as an individual database entry.

I started writing my own script from scratch to parse the PHP file, but it seemed like this really ought to be something someone else has already done before. So before reinventing the wheel I thought I'd ask if any of you know of another way to do it?

I found get_defined_functions() which provided the function names currently loaded.  But I'm looking for the function's arguments, contents and its comments as well.

Comment: Do you mean something like [Nikic's Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser)? Though I'm unsure why you'd want to log all these details in a database.... surely the standard is to use PHPDocumentor

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your response! I'm not trying to document it, I just plan to do some reporting based on when code changes, for qa types of purposes. For example, knowing that a the file was edited recently isn't as helpful as knowing that a particular function in the file was edited.  That sort of reporting.  I'm just hoping to find a way to log the exact function code each time it changes.  Thanks!

Comment: Surely that's the type of information that a version control system like github, mercurial or svn can provide

Comment: Do you need to know what the changes were or simple that a change was made at a given time?  It may be useful to actually hash the functions, with like sha256 or similar, then you can compare the hashes easily to see that it changed. I'm actually building a caching system based of hashing the file contents.  Id also suggest looking into the Reflection Classes in php.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php), which takes a PHP source file and parses it into its components (keywords, comments, whitespace, strings, etc.).

If what you trying to do is analyze performance, such as logging slow calls, you will need a debugger like [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/).

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for your response! I'm mostly intending to use it for reporting purposes, when code changes, etc.  I tested out the token_get_all() function, but all it seems to do is break apart every bit of the code into separate pieces. Which I'm having a hard time understanding how that would help me.